# Сохранить данные из переменной в переменную

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть переменная

```
$message = $update["message"];
$update["message"] = последние сообщение от клиента в telegram bot;
```

Как сохранить это последнее сообщение в переменную для дальнейшего использования, или может записывать в текстовый файл, потом из него читать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы хотите в итоге получить

Comment: @Дмитрий есть telegram bot с webhook, последние сообщение которое пишет клиент боту выводиться в переменную $update["message"]. Нужно сохранить это последние сообщение в переменную. Как это сделать потому что если клиент напишет второй раз то эта переменная $update["message"] будет равна второму значению, а мне нужно сохранить первое значение.

Comment: ну можно использовать $_SESSION (http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php) как вариант, туда в массив сбрасывать все значения, а после последнее брать array_pop (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: сессия потенциально может и не дождить до следующего обращения клиента. но записывать куда то надо, в БД проще всего.

Comment: ну тогда логичнее всего хранить в БД, использовать файлы не рекомендую

Comment: @Дмитрий поможете с кодом?

Comment: покажите, что у Вас есть, помогу